# Is there something wrong with my Vlookup formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

[image]

I have **sheet1** which contains a list of player names and recorded time. In **"C"** column,
a IF condition is used to determine if the player fails or passes the time requirement comparing the recorded time(in Sheet1) and the expected time (which is listed in Sheet2).
In **"D"**, I use the Vlookup to list out the expected timing for each player respectively and it seems to be working as
it is supposedly to be.
But in row 5, it gives a  **False** result when it should be No as 10:00AM is more than the 6:00AM..

**IF + Vlookup:**

```
 =IF(B5>VLOOKUP(A5,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,0), "NO","OK")
```

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you think you are entering times but in fact they are text strings, and are being compared lexicographically (so that "1" is less than "6"). You want to actually compare times. Enter all the times like `6:00` (no `AM`), or make sure you have a space between the number and the AM (as in `6:00 AM`) and you will get the desired results, as shown in the image below. [image: Excel screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your values are texts, so try your formula combined with VALUE

`=IF(VALUE(B5)>VALUE(VLOOKUP(A5,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$4,2,0)), "NO","OK")`

> [VALUE
> function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/value-function-257d0108-07dc-437d-ae1c-bc2d3953d8c2)